# How to fetch if a new query has been added

Tags: php, mysql

```
while($fetchres = mysql_fetch_array($searchquery)) { 
        $v1 = $fetchres['v1']; $v2 = $fetchres['v2']; $v3 = $fetchres['v3']; 
        $v4 = $fetchres['v4']; $v5 = $fetchres['v5'];
        $v6 = $fetchres['v6']; 
        $v7 = $fetchres['v7'];
        }
```

Hi! How can I set this columns automatically? I mean my system automatically adds a column. For example my system adds a new column 'v8'. But in my code, I only inputted until v7. How can I automatically code this fetching of query by depending on how many columns my system automatically made? Thanks.

Comment: You already have a dynamic number of values **in the array `$fetchres`**. Why do you need to put them into variables?

Comment: @deceze so that I can "echo" it.

Comment: @glove you can always echo `$fetchres['v1']`, right?

Comment: Please write the rest of your intended code, it seems you are asking for something that you already have.

Comment: @deceze Yes. but I have manually coded $v1 to $v7. my question is what if in my system I automatically added a new column named v8, and I didn't make a $v8. I put v1 to v7 each into variables so that I can echo them.

Comment: You're approaching this wrong. If you set a new variable, you will later need to refer to it somewhere as well. Extracting the value into its own variable is the easy part, using it later is the hard part without modifying your code over and over. Arrays are there to solve exactly that problem, since they can contain a variable number of elements without the need to keep adding more variable names in your code. **Use arrays!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [extract](http://php.net/extract).

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchQuery))
{
  // Extract the keys of the array into the local symbol table.
  extract($row);

  // Now, all variables exist and you can echo them like this:
  echo $v1;
  echo $v8;
}
```

You still need to know the names of the variables. If you just want to echo everything inside, use foreach with a key assingnment:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchQuery))
{
  foreach($row as $key => $value) 
  {
    echo "$key: $value\n"; // Will output something like 'v1: foo' and 'v2: bar', separated by newlines.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the exact answer that I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, you can use `extract($fetchres)`.

More info about [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Example:

```
$fetchres = array('v1'=>'foo', 'v2'=>'bar');
extract($fetchres);
echo '$v1 is ' . $v1 . 'and $v2 is ' . $v2;
```

Comment: hi. can you please explain how I can use this? can you make an example out of my problem? thanks a lot

Comment: What if $fetchres was not an array? What if $fetchres = mysql_fetch_array($searchquery)?

Comment: You are using it in the `while` condition, what else will you get?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for that, although I think this is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually want this:

```
while ($fetchres = mysql_fetch_array($searchquery)) {
    foreach ($fetchres as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . ': ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```